# SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser; return wrong user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

when execute this statement `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` it gives me user `SharePoint\system` and when I execute this statement

```
if (profileManager.UserExists(username))
                        { }
```

it says user not found.

I logged in with `SharePoint\spadmin`. why it is returning wrong user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your spadmin is the system user

have a look at [here](http://vogtland.ws/markedwardvogt/?p=1016): 
or [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d8d4451f-6fb7-4e98-a4ef-ca05c8c0c300/about-sharepointsystem-what-account-is-it-how-is-it-determined?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)